# How create DatabaseChangeLog from xom XML document?

Tags: liquibase

After doing some in-program manipulation, I end up with an xom Document object containing the ChangeLog I want to execute. From my understanding, I have to convert this to the liquibase XML format, ParsedNode with the help of a ChangeLogParser. But the interface assumes an external representation in the parse method. Using the ResourceAccessor to inject the Document object into the parser is also impossible as the method getResourcesAsStream returns a set of InputStream's.
So the only way I can think of to use the liquibase infrastructure is to execute a Document print to a String and the feed it back via a ByteArrayInputStream. 
Or do i need to write an standalone Document -> ParsedNode converter?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a no-brainer. After a quick look at the SAX hander, this worked:

```
import liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog;
import liquibase.exception.SetupException;
import liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNode;
import liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import nu.xom.Document;
import nu.xom.Element;
import nu.xom.Elements;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

/**
 * Convert a xom Document containing a liquibase changelog
 * to a DatabaseChangeLog.
 */
public class XOMDocumentToDatabaseChangeLogConverter {
    /**
     * Convert the Document ot a DatabaseChangeLog.
     * @param changeLogXML to convert.
     * @return contained changelog.
     * @throws SetupException on error.
     * @throws ParsedNodeException on error.
     */
    public static DatabaseChangeLog convert(Document changeLogXML) throws SetupException, ParsedNodeException {
        DatabaseChangeLog result = new DatabaseChangeLog();
        result.setPhysicalFilePath("");
        Element rootElement = changeLogXML.getRootElement();
        result.load(convert(rootElement), new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Internal recursive method doing the node rollup.
     * @param element to convert.
     * @return converted node.
     * @throws ParsedNodeException on error.
     */
    protected static ParsedNode convert(Element element) throws ParsedNodeException {
        ParsedNode node = new ParsedNode(null, element.getLocalName());
        for (int i = 0; i < element.getAttributeCount(); ++i) {
            node.addChild(null, element.getAttribute(i).getLocalName(), element.getAttribute(i).getValue());
        }
        String seenText = element.getValue();
        if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(seenText).equals("")) {
            node.setValue(seenText.trim());
        }

        Elements children = element.getChildElements();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i) {
            node.addChild(convert(children.get(i)));
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```